# vba code to find and replace text across columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have spent the day trying to learn vba code and searching other questions for the same example but have been unable to crack this so help would be greatly appreciated.

I have worked out how to do it in vlookup but only to a single row.

This code from kutools is the closest i could find and almost does what i need but is only reading single digits in my range (which goes up to 700) so the value i return is multiples of the value string. This would need to be modified to only search and replace the specific value. http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1873-excel-find-and-replace-multiple-values-at-once.html

I have 3 columns: A has a random list of numbers, many repeating; B has a list of reference numbers which correlate to a place name in C.

A   | B   |  C
1   | 1   |  Melbourne
1   | 2   |  Adelaide
1   | 3   |  Sydney
2   | 7   |  Auckland
2   |     |
3   |     |
7   |     |

The code should result in the number in column A being replaced by a place name from column C by first finding the matching number in column B. Note: There are less rows in columns B&C than there are in column A.

There are thousands so i need a code to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well first off I'd place the VLOOKUP data into a new column so to preserve your original data set, but here's the code that you should be looking for:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$C$4,2,FALSE)
```

Here's the syntax of a VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])
```

Now for each part. The **lookup_valu**e is what you're using as a reference to search for, this will be your information for columb A. The **table_array** is a static reference of where to look for this value, and then the resulting values you want to display, so in your sheet you'll make this all of columb B and C. The **col_index_num** represents the index of the table_array you chose previously, so since the name of the cities is in the second column of this table, we put 2. **range_lookup** is whether or not you want an exact match. We do, so we set it to true. And then you can just replicate this value down a column to have the results for everyone.

That should be exactly what you're looking for. I even created a test sheet to try it out. In the future I suggest posting the code you've already tried.